Как правильно разместить бэкенд на ubuntu?
У меня есть сервер, который подключен к домену, где в папке var/www/домен расположен фронт сайта. Также у меня есть сервер на node.js. Как мне связать SSL сертификат домена сайта и сервер? То есть чтобы сервер был на этом домене, по адресу, например server.domain.com

У вас nodejs сервер который отдает контент или он служит только для API запросов? Если API то как у вас отдается фронт, NGINX/Apache/ETC? По хорошему вам необходимо закрыть nodejs  внешние порты и оставить на сервере только 80/443 и при обращении к домену должен отдаваться статический контент, а при обращении к api.domain.com или domain.com/api отдаваться бэкенд сервер, это легко делается если у вас стоит NGINX. Попробуйте развернуть стек NGINX (public site + backend server) похожий вопрос. P.S. используете ли докер?

@MoloF Докер - нет,  нужен только для API, может я неправильно вопрос задал, можно наверное не размещать  на субдомене. Я запускаю node https сервер и отправляю запросы на него с фронта - ошибка: недействительный сертификат, сертификат сгенерированный, есть еще сертификат к домену, можно ли использовать его?

Вы NGINX используете? да или нет? Там сразу всё из коробки работать будет, укажите публичную папку и правило для бэкенд сервиса и всё без проблем заработает.
